# Fazer com que atualize a página e apareça a mensagem em seguida

Tags: php, javascript

Olá,
Como faço para quando enviar um formulario de contato por exemplo, dar um refresh na página e mostrar a mensagem de envio?

Code:
Javascript:

```
function showAlert(type, message)
{
    if (message !== '')
    {
        if (type === '')
        {
            type = 'success';
            type = 'danger';
            type = 'info';
            type = 'warning';
        }
        $('#alert').removeClass();
        $('#alert').addClass('alert alert-' + type).html(message).slideDown();
        setTimeout("closeAlert()", 15000);
}

$(function ()
{
    $('#alert').click(function ()
    {
        closeAlert();
    });
});

function closeAlert()
{
    $('#alert').slideUp();
    $('#alert').removeClass();
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id='alert'></div>
```

PHP:

```
echo "<script>
window.onload = function ()
{
showAlert('success', 'Perfil atualizado com sucesso.');
};
</script>";
```

Exibindo a mensagem de outra forma, só que me parece haver falhas de segurança nisso se não der um jeito..
**messages.php**

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['action']))
{
    $action = $_GET['action'];

    if($action=='registered')
    {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-success">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
        <strong>Sucesso!</strong> avaliação cadastrada obrigado pela colaboração.
        </div>';
    }
}
?>
```

Ai eu incluo as mensagem onde eu quiser:

```
include("/system/messages.php");
```

e chamo via _GET:

```
echo '<script language= "JavaScript">
location.href="?p=cadastro&action=registered";
</script>';
```

Com isso o *invasor* pode, por exemplo, colocar um caminho de um script externo no lugar da variável:
http://www.meusite.com.br/?p=http://sitedumal.net/deleta-banco.php
O seu site incluiria o arquivo normalmente e executaria tudo que existe dentro dele… O resto você já pode imaginar.

Fazer de um modo seguro:

```
// Define uma lista com os array que poderão ser chamados na URL
    $allowed = array($nomeUsuario, 'perfil-updated', 'perfil-updated-error');

 // Verifica se a variável $_GET['action'] existe E se ela faz parte da lista de arquivos permitidos
    if (isset($_GET['action']) AND (array_search($_GET['action'], $allowed) !== false))
    {
        $action = $_GET['action'];
        if($action=='perfil-updated')
        {
            echo '<div class="alert alert-success">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
            <strong>Sucesso!</strong> Perfil atualizado.
            </div>';
        }
        if($action=='perfil-updated-error')
        {
            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
            <strong>Erro ao atualizar!</strong> Não foi possível atualizar o perfil.
            </div>';
        }
    }
    else
    {
// Se não existir variável $_GET ou ela não estiver na lista de permissões, define um valor padrão
        echo '<script language= "JavaScript">
        location.href="?p=profile&action='.$nomeUsuario.'";
        </script>';
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eu já dei +1 na resposta do Pro Hands, pois acho que vai ser difícil ter solução mais simples e objetiva que que essa.

Só postei uma variante, para que fique claro para o autor da pergunta como evitar de alguém mostrar mensagens arbitrárias (o que não teria risco nenhum de segurança, por sinal).

Em vez de passar a mensagem pela *query*, passaria-se o código dela apenas (você pode fazer isto mantendo o redirect original, para evitar envios duplicados):

```
http://pagina.com/diretorio?msg=1
```

E na parte do $_GET, você escolhe a mensagem com o código desejado:

```php
 <?php
    // convertendo o GET para numero
    $msg = isset( $_GET["msg"] ) ? abs( intval( $_GET["msg"] ) ) : 0;

    // de acordo com o numero, mostramos a mensagem correspondente:
    if( $msg == 1 ) {
       echo 'Parabéns, você conseguiu!';
    } elseif ( $msg == 2 ) {
       echo 'Faltou preencher o campo recomendação';
    } elseif ( $msg == 3 ) {
       echo 'Já existe cadastro neste email';
    } else {
       // se o número da mensagem não for 1, 2 ou 3:
       echo 'Ocorreu um problema com a mensagem de retorno.';
    }
    ...
```

Claro que aí no seu código você põe quantos `elseif` precisar, e numera as mensagens de acordo com o caso real.

### "Enxugando" o código com *array*:

No lugar do echo, pode simplesmente usar um *array* com os valores, deixando o código bem curto e fácil de manter:

```
    $msgs = array(
       'Ocorreu um problema com a mensagem de retorno.',  // 0
       'Parabéns, você conseguiu!',                       // 1
       'Faltou preencher o campo recomendação',           // 2
       'Já existe cadastro neste email'                   // 3
    );

    // pega a mensagem e converte em numero
    $msg = isset( $_GET["msg"] ) ? abs( intval( $_GET["msg"] ) ) : 0;

    // se for maior do que o numero de mensagens, usa a mensagem 0
    $msg = if( $msg > count( $msgs ) ? 0 : $msg );

    echo '<div class="mensagem">' . htmlentities( $msgs[$msg] ) . '</div>';
```

### Aplicando estilos

Se quiser usar estilos diferentes por mensagem:

```
    $msgs = array(
       'Ocorreu um problema com a mensagem de retorno.',  // 0
       'Parabéns, você conseguiu!',                       // 1
       'Faltou preencher o campo recomendação',           // 2
       'Já existe cadastro neste email'                   // 3
    );

    $estilos = array(
       'vermelho-desastre',  // 0
       'verde-do-bem',       // 1
       'vermelho-erro',      // 2
       'vermelho-erro'       // 3
    );

    $msg = isset( $_GET["msg"] ) ? abs( intval( $_GET["msg"] ) ) : 0;
    $msg = if( $msg > count( $msgs ) ? 0 : $msg );

    echo '<div class="'.$estilos[$msg].'">'.htmlentities( $msgs[$msg] ).'</div>';
```

Answer (score 6):

Uma forma simples é usando `$_GET` com a mensagem (codificando-a para o URL) na página.

Exemplo:

```
"http://pagina.com/diretorio?msg=Hello2F%Welcome"
```

Aí, faça um echo no $_GET["msg"] se existir, onde você quiser.

Seria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
<div class="_dTC">
    <div class="_vAM">
        <?php
        if(isset($_GET["msg"])){
            echo $_GET["msg"];
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sim, via _GET eu conseguiu fazer, só que tem dá problemas de segurança pro site

Comment: Editei meu post, de uma olhada por favor

Comment: Basicamente, todos tipos de método que você usar vão resultar no mesmo. Qualquer pessoa pode postar algo para o URL ou criar um cookie. Para evitar essa "insegurança" você deve usar condições `if` para checar se tal coisa está incorreta, se está vázia ou se já existe. Espero que lhe seja útil.

Answer (score 2):

Salve uma flag em cookie e verifique se existe.

Essa técnica é útil também para prevenir envios duplicados. Contudo, não vamos abordar aqui as regras para bloqueio de envio duplicado.

**Exemplo de técnica usando somente JavaScript**

```
function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    var date, expires;
    if (days) {
        date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    } else {
        expires = "";
    }
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

if (document.cookie.indexOf("updated") >= 0) {
    alert("ok, foi atualizado");

    // Remove o cookie
    createCookie("updated", 1, -1);
}else{
    // Cria o cookie
    createCookie("updated", 1, 1);
}
```

Caso esteja usando o Google Chrome, poderá verificar a execução pelo "Developer tools" -> Resources -> Cookies

Nessa imagem, é o estado inicial, quando o cookie foi gerado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dê um novo refresh e então surgirá o alerta. Isso acontece porque nesse momento o cookie existe.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Clique em OK para fechar o alerta. Observe que no developer tools que o cookie foi removido.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Um exemplo mais real com PHP e HTML**

Esse é o script PHP onde recebe dados de um formulário. Vamos chamar de "tmp.php"

```
// Recebeu de um formulário, fez as firulas que tinha que fazer e agora está setando o cookie:
if (isset($_GET['foo']))
{
    $cookie_name = 'updated';
    $cookie_value = 1;
    setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), '/'); // 86400 = 1 day

    /**
    Isso é necessário quando precisar acessar o cookie na corrente sessão pelo PHP pois a função setcookie() não atualiza os headers. 
    Caso não necessite, apenas remova ou comente a linha abaixo.
    */
    $_COOKIE[$cookie_name] = $cookie_value;
}

/**
Aqui pode fazer um include ou um header(location:...)
Um include consumirá menos em requisições, mas consumirá mais memória pois o PHP vai parsear o arquivo incluso.
Utilize o que for conveniente para o seu caso.
*/
include 'tmp.html';

//header("location: http://localhost/tmp.html");
```

Esse é a página HTML contendo o formulário e um verificador do cookie. Vamos chamar de "tmp.html"

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>test</title>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<script type="text/javascript">

function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    var date, expires;
    if (days) {
        date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    } else {
        expires = "";
    }
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

if (document.cookie.indexOf("updated") >= 0) {
    alert("ok, foi atualizado");

    // Remove o cookie
    createCookie("updated", 1, -1);
}
</script>


</head>
<body>

<form action="tmp.php" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="foo" value="1" />
<input type="submit" value="enviar" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Para testar, acesse a página HTML. Exemplo: `http://localhost/tmp.html`

Pressione o botão "enviar". Será direcionado para `http://localhost/tmp.php?foo=1` onde o JavaScript verificará que o cookie existe, emitirá o alert() e logo em seguida removerá o cookie.